# Дубликаты в автоинкрементальном поле

Tags: mysql, триггер, репликация, autoincrement

Задача не совсем обычная. Скажу сразу, это временное решение.

Итак, есть исходная MYSQL база данных (назовём, MASTER) и его реплика (пусть, SLAVE). Реплицирование (как уже понятно, MASTER-SLAVE) statement-based по причине, что на SLAVE нужно запускать триггеры.

1. Свои триггеры на SLAVE были удалены и заменены новым набором.
2. Для каждой таблицы создано по 3 триггера: на INSERT, на UPDATE и на DELETE.
3. Все триггеры созданы на основе одного шаблона и отличаются только передаваемыми значениями.
4. Каждый триггер делает 1 INSERT в таблицу (назовём, CHANGES) в SLAVE.
5. Таблица CHANGES присутствует только на SLAVE. На MASTER ничего о ней не знают и не работают с ней. С таблицей CHANGES работают только триггеры на SLAVE.
6. В таблице CHANGES есть автоинкрементальное поле ID (bigint).
7. Ни один триггер не пишет напрямую значение этого поля. Значение заполняется по умолчанию базой данных.
8. За минуту в таблицу CHANGES добавляется около 20 записей.
9. По мере работы системы возникают дубликаты для поля ID.

Как такое может возникать?

Странно ещё то, что каждый раз дублированное значение на немного отличается от предыдущего в большую сторону. Больше похоже на значение какого-то автоинкремента, но только не этой таблицы.

Итак, ещё раз цепочка действий:

1. В MASTER происходит INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE таблицы.
2. Это изменение переносится репликацией в SLAVE.
3. На SLAVE срабатывает соответствующий триггер, который создаёт запись в CHANGES.
4. Периодически, возникают дубликаты для незатрагиваемого запросами поля ID таблицы CHANGES.

Могу сразу сказать, что ни один триггер точно не затрагивает значение поля ID. И никто другой тоже. Никаких UPDATE / DELETE над CHANGES тоже не выполняется.

Я понимаю, что два и больше разных триггеров могу сработать одновременно и, соответственно, будут делать INSERT тоже одновременно. Но такая ситуация должна без особых сложностей разрешаться самой СУБД. Иначе, это была бы очень плохая СУБД.

**UPD:**

```
CREATE TABLE `CHANGES` (
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`field1` ENUM(...) NOT NULL,
`field2` BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
`field3` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`field4` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`field5` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TRIGGER `tr_TABLE_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `TABLE`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `CHANGES` (`field1`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`)
    VALUES ("value1", "value3", "value4", "value5");
END
```

**UPD 2:**

Пока использовать очень некрасивое решение - добавление BEFORE INSERT триггера для CHANGES, который вручную устанавливает значение ID.

Это работает. Но я до сих пор не понимаю почему родной механизм AUTO_INCREMENT генерирует дублирующие значения.

Comment: а на поле ID что ли нет уникального индекса или первичного ключа ?

Comment: и оно точно auto_increment, а не ведется какими то другими механизмами ?

Comment: Поле ID  - NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT и PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Я с таким поведением сталкиваюсь в первый раз. Подобное я делал не раз, но только сейчас добавлена репликация. Может для SLAVE реплики значение автоинкремента генерироваться иначе? Я сомневаюсь.

Comment: эм ... мистика. даже если бы механизм автоинкремента дал сбой (что уже представляется невозможным) то первичный ключ не должен был бы позволить записать такую запись. (если конечно не выключена проверка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210608/mysql-disable-enable-keys).

Comment: Нет, ничего не выключено. Для меня это тоже странно. На MASTER сделано подобное, но работа идёт с другой таблицей и там всё работает.

Comment: ну судя по официальной документации https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html при репликации уже поймано несколько багов с автоинкрементом. правда там речь я так понял идет о самой реплицируемой таблице. в общем подождем может придет кто то  работавший с репликацией и сталкивавшийся. Не сильно удивлюсь если это баг

Comment: Да, это я уже читал. Я знаю, что при statement-based репликации могут возникать ошибки, если будет изменено значение автоинкрементального поля на MASTER. Есть в этом моменте некоторые заморочки. Но тут, таблица только на SLAVE, она не реплицируется, добавления инициируются новым набором триггеров.